# Understating python to java code translation to generate Access token for an Oauth API

Tags: java, python

Below is the code used to get the Accesstoken for Alice Blue API and we are getting 403 error while generating the access token. Please help us resolve this issue.

For Auth Code Generation I have constructed a URL and opened in broser and copied the code for using in Java

```
# Get Access Token Python code
params = {
'code': code,
'redirect_uri': redirect_url,
'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
'client_secret': api_secret,
"cliend_id": username
}
url = f "https://accesstokenURL?client_id={app_id}&client_secret= {api_secret}&grant_type=authorization_code&code={code}&redirect_uri={redirect_url}&authorization_response={resp.url}"
resp = r.post(url, auth = (app_id, api_secret), data = params)
resp = json.loads(resp.text)
if ('access_token' in resp):
    access_token = resp['access_token']
    logger.info(f 'access_token - {access_token}')
    return access_token
```

I tried to replicate above python code in Java to generate access Token, i have used following code.Its giving me 403 error.

```
Java Code:
try {
    String auth = "app_id:App_sec";
    String urlParameters = "{\"client_id\":\"app_id(will replace)\",\"client_secret\":\"app_sec(will replace)\",\"grant_type\":\"authorization_code\",\"code\":\"authcode(will replace)\",\"redirect_uri\":\"http://localhost:3000\",\"authorization_response\":\"https://ant.aliceblueonline.com/plugin/callback/?code=-RWi-mC2mOU9ccAinLzEOvXgDnXLnkkrukgT95Yn1-4.XQhOG3yOdX4N1GecnIv9coL5hnJnAjmsFzwgzic&scope=&state=test_state\"}";
    URL url = new URL("https://ant.aliceblueonline.com/oauth2/token/");
    String encoding = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(auth.getBytes());

    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);

    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    InputStream content = (InputStream) connection.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader in =
        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
    String line;
    while ((line = in .readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use okhttp or plain java connection is the requirement?

Comment: I can't see where you pass  client_id and other query string parameters that you pass in python code

Comment: @silentsudo anything is fine

Comment: @DenisYakovlev in the python code its passed as a parameter right

Comment: I mean try to pass parameters in url: URL url = new URL("https://ant.aliceblueonline.com/oauth2/token/?client_id={app_id}&client_secret= {api_secret}&grant_type=authorization_code&code={code}&redirect_uri={redirect_url}&authorization_response={resp.url}");